# Initializing a tuple's elements with non-const references to another tuple's elements of different type

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17

I'm trying to do a conversion initialization of an `std::tuple` (called `w`) with elements from another `std::tuple` (called `t`) with same size but different element types.

In my application, the elements of `w` must be constructed using a `non-const reference` to the respective element of `t`.

Unfortunately, there only exists a `4) converting copy-ctor` and a `5) converting move-ctor` for `std::tuple` ([reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple)). This means, the new element from `w` can only be initialized using either a `const reference` or `rvalue reference` to the element of `t`, and both are not applicable.

### Example

First we have a element modifier class, that only binds to references of its element type.

```
template<typename T>
struct SingleElementModifier {
    T& ref;
    SingleElementModifier(T& ref) : ref(ref) { }
};
```

Next a type trait to get the type of `w` given the type of `t`. Essentially it wraps each element from `t` into the `SingleElementModifier`.

```
template<typename T> struct ModifierTuple;
template<typename... Ts>
struct ModifierTuple<std::tuple<Ts...>> {
    using Type = std::tuple<SingleElementModifier<Ts>...>;
};
```

Now we have a `TupleModifier` that takes a tuple `t` and stores a tuple `w` with modifiers to each element of the first tuple.

```
template<typename Tuple>
struct TupleModifier {
    using TupleType = typename ModifierTuple<Tuple>::Type;
    TupleType w;
    TupleModifier(Tuple& t) : w{ t } { }
};
```

Now we only need to choose some tuple `t` and create the modifer.

```
int main() {
    /* just some example types, could be any type inside. */
    std::tuple<double, std::pair<int, int>> t;
    TupleModifier mod(t);
}
```

**[Live example](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5NwDMeFsgYisAag6yAwgREAHBpg3YOABgAipgIKmLJywUwBbfUwcbtAT12YWTR5lUAFSMbK0ECYhFkAlUAZQVgA0CvTABZDDwAMzxMYnUAdj5zK1MATmCuADZVYkxMjSLbaxNS%2BLYklPT8bNyICurazIBKVRAauohBkY5CgtsmmYtZRpLiuwdnZjctAhTffyCjVXDI6NUurJziQL0DBtD1pxdtz299zAA6L6DBELXLE5RGIXHrXW6GLThdAgEA6fQQzSBQRfD4hWTYAorOxlESCBJBFLqWRmY4EaGw8HuNqJTDJbwgq7uJFGFForHWfJLdkPexPLYI3ZvPwBG7wv5NQFnUUGBm5TE8nF4thBcF0gIaEmCnzC84ZUHShEGowwtX3f5lA1q1QAdzNCxaBtlxD6lKqqgIIzGttmMUWmLmCs5dtWEoiQNUPCYxFo/sWwbskpikeIXFjQeWCv%2BChijiYCgg00KmdKUJhcLuWnQogARgZSBGo/QGymjvUM%2BaHeCnapHBgIMN4xz5lYpENGNIAKxSUgsaQmaeoaSafj8Y6icTqriyWjTghz0djgDWIFksg%2Bp4vl6vlXHUgALNPHHQTCYZ/vSIupNPBCBX3upPOY5wLASBoM4eAGGQFAQGBugQbkIDAPksikNkDAOMQP4QNW77VgoUYeNIO6kGB/gsAQADyLAMIRAHTlgubtJIdGkPgtTRHgABumA/ixmAAB6YMgIgOER07ZpgDDvhEeBPlIO5jswbAoCuvCMHg1Y/pAY6oLoBB4KgLC8QAtFCGqcLw/C0PkqjGd46CsPpyC2QA6kwDAMN%2B64SHQimTtOs4sZ%2B/EAByVMZlR3qowDIM5%2BTnqoEC4IQJDqFuTaaKg4GQWl24jMulm8Lu%2B5DEeIB3iYHwThOlRhSFpRcDVlSyFwd4TreD6kE%2BtAvm%2BQXSN%2Bv6kP%2BgGkMBiAgKIBC6CJ5CULB8HEHQpCYPgRBLbQflSFOfXzh%2B0hyDG1qEAgqiheFkXRbFqjxbIxV0aVpDHlUHw9aU%2BTvfkd49SYsjfVwHWPs%2Br6BXtn6DX%2BJVbVwAXvuDw1Q6Q3GYQZs53kAA)**

Here the compiler will stop and complain to me that no constructor for `w{ t }` could be found, for the reason explained in the beginning.

### Bad workaround

Theoretically, I could have `SingleElementModifier` take a `const T&` and use `const_cast` to get rid of the const, but I was hoping for a better solution that doesn't require me to throw away const-correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a little indirection:

```
template<typename Tuple>
struct TupleModifier {
    using TupleType = typename ModifierTuple<Tuple>::Type;
    TupleType w;
    TupleModifier(Tuple& t)
        : TupleModifier{ t, std::make_index_sequence<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>() }
    {}

private:
    template <std::size_t ... Is>
    TupleModifier(Tuple& t, std::index_sequence<Is...>) : w{ std::get<Is>(t)...} { }
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8910aa31375d3443)